# How to implement array signature method in typescript

Tags: typescript

**Trying to get this to compile:**

```
interface ListInterface {
    getObject(index: number): Object;
    [index: number]: Object;
}

class List123 implements ListInterface {
    private list: Object[] = [1,2,3];
    getObject(index: number) { return this.list[index] }
    [index: number] { return this.getObject(index) }
}
```

**but tsc is emitting:**

> Unexpected '[' in class definition on the [ ] method declaration.

[Typescript Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20ListInterface%20%7B%0A%09getObject%28index%3a%20number%29%3a%20Object;%0A%09%5Bindex%3a%20number%5D%3a%20Object;%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20List123%20implements%20ListInterface%20%7B%0A%09private%20list%3a%20Object%5B%5D%20=%20%5B1,2,3%5D;%0A%09getObject%28index%3a%20number%29%20%7B%20return%20this.list%5Bindex%5D%20%7D%0A//?%09%5Bindex%3a%20number%5D%20%7B%20return%20this.getObject%28index%29%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20list%20=%20new%20List123%28%29;%0A%0Aalert%28list.getObject%281%29.toString%28%29%29) (uncomment the //? for the issue I'm having)

Answer (score 5):

Some type annotations are there for defining JavaScript behaviour and cannot be implemented - the indexer annotation is one such example.

Please refer to the [related discussion on codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/398379).

For the code sample provided in the question, there is a partial solution because JavaScript objects naturally support indexer notation. Hence one can write:

```
interface ListInterface {
    getObject(index: number): Object;
}

class List123 implements ListInterface {

    getObject(index: number) { 
        return <Object> this[index] 
    }
}

var list  = new List123();
list[1] = "my object";

console.log(list[1]); // "my object"
console.log(list.getObject(1)); // "my object";
```