# Implementing an indexer in a class in TypeScript

Tags: class, typescript, indexer

Is it currently possible to implement an indexer on a class in TypeScript?

```
class MyCollection {
   [name: string]: MyType;       
}
```

This doesn't compile. I can specify an indexer on an interface, of course, but I need methods on this type as well as the indexer, so an interface won't suffice.

Thanks.

Comment: No: see http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/398379 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791550/how-to-implement-array-signature-method-in-typescript and

Comment: The code above is now legal and compiles in the latest versions of TypeScript

Comment: @RichN but then you can't add methods

Answer (score 43):

You cannot implement a class with an indexer. You can create an interface, but that interface cannot be implemented by a class. It can be implemented in plain JavaScript, and you can specify functions as well as the indexer on the interface:

```
class MyType {
    constructor(public someVal: string) {

    }
}

interface MyCollection {   
   [name: string]: MyType;
}

var collection: MyCollection = {};

collection['First'] = new MyType('Val');
collection['Second'] = new MyType('Another');

var a = collection['First'];

alert(a.someVal);
```

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question, for those looking for the answer: now it's possible to define a indexed property like:

`let lookup : {[key:string]:AnyType};`

the signature of the key must be either string or integer see:

[Interfaces on www.typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Comment: The question is about classes, not interfaces. And if you add such an indexer on a class, it can no longer have normal methods that don't return an `AnyType`. This answer is not correct for the question asked. What the question asks for is still not possible.

Answer (score 10):

Is not possible to define an indexed property getter/setter in a class but you can "simulate" that in a way like this using [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```
class IndexedPropSample  {
  [name: string | symbol]: any;

  private static indexedHandler: ProxyHandler<IndexedPropSample> = {
    get(target, property) {
      return target[property];
    },
    set(target, property, value): boolean {
        target[property] = value;
        return true;
    }
  };

  constructor() {
      return new Proxy(this, IndexedPropSample.indexedHandler);
  }

  readIndexedProp = (prop: string | symbol): any => {
      return this[prop];
  }

}


var test = new IndexedPropSample();

test["propCustom"] = "valueCustom";

console.log(test["propCustom"]); // "valueCustom"
console.log(test.readIndexedProp("propCustom")); // "valueCustom"
console.log(test instanceof IndexedPropSample); // true
console.log(Object.keys(test)); // ["propCustom", "readIndexedProp"]
```

you can try it in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=true#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-vg5qgE0tXqNWtAdpgDqdLo1PGRhOJaHRfliOoyVu9WtyfsDwYtOcj0fusZR8ddMsERmQYHQhAAZkg06SEQEaAWg2d0GX7ZXnbEAPLSABW6BeyIA1ugJDBqzx86oA0HtSmFXgMlq0lmSCWffBQEA)

Answer (score 3):

@Dardino: Thant helped a lot. Thanks.
In case anybody also needs to do function calls and access properties through the proxy, here is some code based on Dardinos's one.

```
  private static indexedHandler: ProxyHandler<IndexedPropSample> = {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (typeof prop === "string" && !(typeof target[prop as string])) {
        // Array access
        return target.getItem(prop);
      }
      else if ((typeof prop === "string" && typeof target[prop as string] === "function")) {
        // function call
        return target[prop].bind(target);
      } else if (typeof prop === "string") {
        // property access
        return target[prop];
      }

      return undefined;
    },
    set(target, prop, value): boolean {
      if (typeof prop === "string" && !(typeof target[prop as string])) {
        // Array access
        target.setItem(prop, value);
        return true;
      } else if (typeof prop === "string") {
        // property access
        return target[prop] = value;
      }
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have static methods, though:

```
class MyCollection {
    [name: string]: string;
    static print(collection: MyCollection) {
        console.log(collection);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhA9iEBTYAXAlsgdtAN4BQ050A2vmALboBc0EWATjvgOYC6TL7XANxkKLMLmDQADgKwAKYKgzY8%20JghRpMuAgEpiIihUX4IqdADoQyTgqXbVu4UYC%20JNyZbRJAXmj50AHc4JHsVAjknEmALMGg-AHIwBOEYgCN46AS0lJINMJ18CxkOeWAnIA)