# How to mimic indexers in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to use Indexers in typescript like C# Indexers.
For example,

```
class example {
  public this[row: number, column: number];
}
```

Is this possible in Typescript?

Indexers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers

Comment: It would require a decent amount of code generation from typescript so it is not possible since TS is trying to be as close as possible to plain JS.

Comment: @JakeWeary Can you suggest a close alternative that I can opt for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing an indexer in a class in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841598/implementing-an-indexer-in-a-class-in-typescript)

Comment: Just define regular `get()` `set()` methods on your class?