# Property 'selected' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'Field'

Tags: typescript

on this piece of code

```
export interface Field {
  selected:  boolean;
  value: any;
}

export interface ConflictingVersionModel {
  [key: string]: Field;
  selected: boolean;
}
```

I get this error:
TS2411: Property 'selected' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'Field'.

the same one if I try:

```
export interface ConflictingVersionModel {
  [key: string]: {
    selected:  boolean;
    value: any;
  };
  selected: boolean;
}
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: When you add an indexer to a type, like `[key: string]: Field;`, it means that **all** properties have to return `Field`. In JavaScript you can't override the indexer operator `[]`: it always maps string keys to actual `object` properties.

Comment: @Dai And there is no way to add another property? It seems awful for me to be like this

Comment: You could do `interface ConflictingVersionModel { fields: { [key: string]: Field }; selected: boolean; }`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841598/implementing-an-indexer-in-a-class-in-typescript

Comment: Don't forget to use `readonly` where-appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah that won't work. An index signature means 'all properties of this object have this type'.

You can however achieve what it looks like you are trying to do using an **intersection type**

```
export interface Field {
  selected:  boolean;
  value: any;
}

type ConflictingVersionModel = {
  [key: string]: Field;
} & { selected: boolean }
```

Comment: But if I do `const val: ConflictingVersionModel = { selected: true }` it will complain `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Field'.`

Comment: Well yeah - because `{ selected: true }` is a more specific type than `{ selected: boolean }`. You can't assign a type _where selected can only be true_ to a type where _selected can be either true or false_

Comment: This example does not seem to work. Here is my test code: https://gist.github.com/martian17/03b7933ca4d3b981c2c8895831ec5d82